# How to test ember models are loaded correctly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am creating a bunch of models to use with ember-data, and I would like to make sure when I perform operations with them like:

```
this.get('store').findRecord('blog-post', 1);
```

That the record returned has the attributes in the format I expect.

I would like to write an integration/acceptance test which calls my actual service, but I have not been able to get access to the store within my tests.

Any recommendations on how to test if my models are configured correctly for my service output.

Comment: Testing serializers is not such easy. But you could have a look how it's done in ember-data. It has several tests for serializers. E.g. this integration test for JsonApiSerializer: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/tests/integration/serializers/json-api-serializer-test.js

Comment: You could also take a look at this other question, the answers he links to have worked for me in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578787/334913